# What are some of the factors involved in multiple near simultaneous interrupts

Tags: interrupt

I know that you can either disable interrupts while the interrupt is going to be processed or you can use a priority scheme. But what happens when the 2 are too close to one another

Answer (score 0):

Even if, supposedly theoretically, multiple interrupts occur at the same time *physically*, interrupts are sampled at the processor's clock rate and then multiple pending interrupt requests handled according to predefined or preconfigured interrupt priorities.

This is usually done by selecting the one with the topmost priority and keeping the interrupt service routine itself from being interrupted, but some processors takes it furthur and allow storing context for each interrupt and makes lower priority ISRs themselves preemptible by higher priority interrupt requests.